# Get item what's not on the 2nd, 3rd arrays - JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that will get the items that cannot be seen on the 2nd or 3rd and upcoming arrays passed within the function.

Right now my function gets only the similar items. How can I make it get the difference (w/c are the items that doesn't exist to the 2nd and 3rd and proceeding arrays.

```
const callM = function(arrays) {
   arrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);


   let result = [];

  for(let i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++){
    for(let x = 0; x < arrays[i].length; x++){
      if(arrays[0].includes(arrays[i][x])){
        result.push(arrays[i][x]);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;

  };

console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10])); // -> must be [1, 3, 4]
console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8])); // -> must be [3,4]
```

The logic right now is a bit off as it gets the opposite. How do i fix this?

Also is there a way to do this using **Higher Order functions** such as **reduce** or **filter**?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding this `console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10])); // -> must be [1, 3, 4]` shouldn't the result be `[1,3,4,10]`

Comment: What is the type of difference should the item not be present in any of the array??

Comment: Actually no. We're only checking arrays[0] here what doesnt exist on the other arrays.

Comment: For instance [1,2,3,4,5] -> obviously [1,3,4] doesn't exist on [5, 2, 10] so we're only concerned about checking arrays[0] here.,We don't care about arrays 2...3...and so on.

Comment: Then this should output `console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8));` will be `[3,4]` isn't it

Comment: correct. My bad there. let me fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think about this differently. As the difference between two sets: array 0 and array 1...n

To get array 0, just shift it off the top

```
const arr0 = arrays.shift()
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

This removes the first array from arrays
Next we combine the remaining arrays

```
const arrN = arrays.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr)
})
```

Ref: http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/flattening-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript/

**Unneeded, handled by `includes` as mentioned by @Phil**

Next filter duplicates from arrN by comparing with itself

```
const unique = arrN.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index == self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Next filter with includes to find the difference (or union)

```
const diff = arr0.filter(function(item) {
    return !arrN.includes(item))
}
```

Full snippet:

```js
function callM(arrays) {

  const arr0 = arrays.shift()
  const arrN = arrays.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr)
  })
  //const unique = arrN.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
  //    return index == self.indexOf(elem)
  //})
  return arr0.filter(function(item) {
    return !arrN.includes(item)
  })
}

console.log(callM([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]]))
console.log(callM([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8]]))
```

of course ES6 would be easier. ;)

```js
const callM = (first, ...rest) => {
  const arrays = [].concat(...rest)
  return first.filter(item => !arrays.includes(item))
}

console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]))
console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8]))
```

Comment: Nice answer but I feel like reducing the combined arrays to their unique values is wasted effort.

Comment: Wasn't up on how includes works. That has the dups covered. Thanks for the comment. Changing

Comment: It's pretty much `arr.indexOf(v) !== -1`

Answer (score 1):

A short solution for small and medium sized arrays:

```js
// Return elements in array but not in filters:
function difference(array, ...filters) {
  return array.filter(el => !filters.some(filter => filter.includes(el)));
}

// Example:
console.log(difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10])); // [1, 3, 4]
console.log(difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 1, 10], [7, 2, 8])); // [3, 4]
```

For large inputs, consider creating a `Set` from all `filters` and filtering in linear time using `set.has(el)`.

In order to fix your implementation, you could label the outer for-loop and continue from there whenever a filter contains one of the array elements. Only when all filters pass without match, you push the array element into the result:

```js
// Return elements in array but not in filters:
function difference(array, ...filters) {
  const result = [];

  loop: for (const el of array) {
    for (const filter of filters) {
      if (filter.includes(el)) continue loop;
    }
    result.push(el);
  }
  return result;
}

// Example:
console.log(difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10])); // [1, 3, 4]
console.log(difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8])); // [3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Underscore, you can do this in one line of code:

```
console.log(_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8]))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o1zuaa6m/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to create object lookup of all the other array excluding the first array. Then use `array#filter` to get the values which are not present in the object lookup

```js
var callM = (first, ...rest) => {  
  var combined = rest
                  .reduce((res,arr) => res.concat(arr))
                  .reduce((o, v) => {
                    o[v] = true;
                    return o;
                  },{}); 
  
  return first
          .filter(v => !combined[v]);
}

console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10])); // -> must be [1, 3, 4]
console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8])); // -> must be [3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way to exclude values is usually to use a lookup hash set with the values to exclude:

```js
const callM = (a, ...b) => (b = new Set(b.concat.apply(...b)), a.filter(v => !b.has(v)))

console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]));              // [1, 3, 4]
console.log(callM([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10], [7, 1, 8]));   // [3, 4]
```